# What's the best way to start using Lift?

Tags: scala, lift, sbt

I'm a Ruby on Rails developer and I'm very intrigued by what Lift has to offer, but I'm having a very hard time getting together some good resources/documentation to start off.

- Should I use Lifty? I can't manage to get it working under sbt 0.12; Is there another tool for code generation?
- Is there a way to see snippet changes live on the development server without spending money on JRebel?
- Going around on some forums i saw that Manning's Lift in Action is not up-to-date; is there any other tutorial-style book I can look into to grasp the basics on how to make a Lift app from scratch? I found many guides but none of them gives me a clear path on how to work with Lift.

Comment: This is not "not constructive": the title is vague, but the specific questions are answerable concisely with facts.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Luigi. I'm really interested in getting some feedback on Lift; if you have any advice on how to improve my question you are welcome to provide for it!

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to see snippet changes live on the development server
>   without spending money on JRebel?

JRebel is free for Scala developers - just get yourself an account at [my.jrebel.com](http://my.jrebel.com)

Comment: Thanks Anton! I'm having a hard time using it with SBT but I'll see if I can get any help on that.